# How to remove a formGroup from form in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using template driven forms and i want to remove a formGroup from the form controls. how can i do that? i have following controls in my form

[image]

as you can see in this image, i have a set of formControls and a formGroup. I want to remove the formGroup, how can i do that?

i am able to remove the formControl inside the formGroup like this

```
const ymmtGroup = <FormGroup>this.form.controls['someGroup'];
ymmtGroup.removeControl('someControl');
```

but not know how to remove the formGroup itself
**UPDATE 1**

i did something like this, just let me know if this is right
var formControls=this.form.controls;
delete formControls.someGroup;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example `this.form` is `FormGroup` by itsself. `someGroup` is just `this.form`'s control (each form group may have another form groups as its child controls). `FormGroup` has [`removeControl()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1189) function, which looks like:

```
  removeControl(name: string): void {
    if (this.controls[name]) this.controls[name]._registerOnCollectionChange(() => {});
    delete (this.controls[name]);
    this.updateValueAndValidity();
    this._onCollectionChange();
  }
```

and which you already used. So, just try:

```
this.form.removeControl('someGroup');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

Proper Way to remove a form Group

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.createForm();
    this.removeGroup();
    console.log(this.myForm.value)

  }

  createForm(){
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      parentGroup: this.fb.group({
        childGroup: this.fb.group({
          control1: null,
          control2:null,
          control3:null
        })
      })
    })
  }

  removeGroup(){
    this.myForm.removeControl('parentGroup');
    this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to remove the formGroup from the form, not formControl from a formGroup

Comment: please see my update and let me know if that is the proper way, if not, then lewt me know the proper way, thanks

Comment: check the proper way to do that

Comment: What is unproper way?  `removeControl()` function (see my answer) has a call to `this.updateValueAndValidity()`. `this` corresponds to the form group (`this.myForm` in our case). So, `this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity()` in your answer is redundant. Regarding your original answer with `this.form.controls.get('someGroup')`: `this.form.controls` is just a key:value JS object, and it does not have `get()` method